# How do I open the hyperlink with Chrome browser in node js application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

I made the file named index.html in node js application but when I click the link it opens via new node js console.

Please refer to this image
[image]

How do I open the hyperlink with Chrome browser?

```
<html>

<body>

<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">GOOGLE</a>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you need to start chrome process with that url

Comment: @sumeetkumar There is no way to open via Chrome without starting Chrome process? Chrome is the default browser on my PC.

Comment: if you have file association like in windows just say process.start with url.. it will choose default browser but it may not be chrome to be sure about chrome you need to run chrome process with url argument